# React Validation of a Large Form

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React app with a simple form (Login) and want to do UI validation. For a simple email and password, I can use the following code but what if I had a form with 8-10 fields. Should I still validate it inside the validate function OR would that make my component larger and messy. In those situations what is the recommended approach to validate a large form in React?

```
function Login() {

    const [userLogin, setUserLogin] = useState({})
    const [loginFormErrors, setLoginFormErrors] = useState({})
    const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false)

    const handleChange = (e) => {
       // code here 
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        // if loginFormErrors is an empty object then submit the form 
        if(Object.keys(loginFormErrors).length == 0 && isValid) {
            console.log('Submit the form')
        }

    }, [loginFormErrors])

    const validate = () => {
        
        let errors = {}

        if(!userLogin.email) {
            errors.email = 'Email is required!'
        } else if(!validateEmail(userLogin.email)) {
            errors.email = 'Email is not in correct format!'
        }
        if(!userLogin.password) {
            errors.password = 'Password is required!'
        }

        return errors
    }

    const handleLogin = () => {
        setLoginFormErrors(validate()) 
        setIsValid(true)      
    }

    return (
       <div>
        <input type = 'text' placeholder='Email' name = 'email' onChange = {handleChange} />
        <p>{loginFormErrors.email}</p>
        <input type = 'password' placeholder='Password' name = 'password' onChange = {handleChange} />
        <p>{loginFormErrors.password}</p>

        <button onClick = {handleLogin}>Login</button>
       </div>
    )
}
```

PS: I got this code from an online sample

Answer (score 0):

In those situations using validation libraries makes form validation easier and more powerful. I would recommend you to use [react-validatable-form](https://obss.github.io/react-validatable-form-demo/).

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-validatable-form-example-e0dzhn) for an example of usage similar to your form.

First, you need to wrap your App inside `ReactValidatableFormProvider` like:

```
import { ReactValidatableFormProvider } from "react-validatable-form";
import "./styles.css";
import Login from "./Login";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ReactValidatableFormProvider
      hideBeforeSubmit={true}
      showAfterBlur={true}
      focusToErrorAfterSubmit={true}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <h1>react-validatable-form Example</h1>
        <Login />
      </div>
    </ReactValidatableFormProvider>
  );
}
```

and then handle the `formData` and validations using the `useValidatableForm` hook.

```
import { useValidatableForm } from "react-validatable-form";

const rules = [
  { path: "email", ruleSet: [{ rule: "required" }, { rule: "email" }] },
  { path: "password", ruleSet: [{ rule: "required" }] }
];

const Login = () => {
  const {
    isValid,
    getValue,
    getError,
    setPathValue,
    setPathIsBlurred,
    setFormIsSubmitted,
    formData
  } = useValidatableForm({ rules: rules });

  const handleLogin = () => {
    setFormIsSubmitted(true);
    if (isValid) {
      alert(
        "form is valid and submmitted, email=" +
          formData.email +
          " password=" +
          formData.password
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Email"
        id="email"
        value={getValue("email")}
        onChange={(e) => setPathValue("email", e.target.value)}
        onBlur={() => setPathIsBlurred("email")}
      />
      <p>{getError("email")}</p>
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        id="password"
        value={getValue("password")}
        onChange={(e) => setPathValue("password", e.target.value)}
        onBlur={() => setPathIsBlurred("password")}
      />
      <p>{getError("password")}</p>

      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
      {"isValid = " + isValid}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```